# How to split a string by a splitter thats outside of the qoutes?

Tags: python, string, split

I have a string
`'"abc"+ h abc "abch"'`

I want it to be splitted by `abc`'s that are outside of the quotes.

After splitting it should be

`['"abc"+ h ','"abch"']`.

It would be amazing if solution doesn't use any modules or libs In python Ofcourse.

Comment: why isn't the desired result ```['"abc"+ h ',' "abch"']```? note the space in ```' "abch"'```

Comment: @BerlinBenilo String can be anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very pythonic, but it works:

```py
def split_outside_quotes(string, sep):
    if sep == "":
        raise ValueError("empty separator")
    
    substrings = []
    in_quote = False
    split_from = 0
    string_len = len(string)
    sep_len = len(sep)
    i = 0
    
    while i < string_len:
        if string[i] == '"':
            in_quote = not in_quote
        
        elif not in_quote:
            if string[i:i+sep_len] == sep:
                substrings.append(string[split_from:i])
                i = split_from = i + sep_len
                continue
        
        i += 1
    
    substrings.append(string[split_from:])
    
    return substrings

string = r'"abc"+ h abc "abch"abc'

print(split_outside_quotes(r'"abc"+ h abc "abch"', "abc"))
print(split_outside_quotes(r'', "abc"))
print(split_outside_quotes(r'"abc"', "abc"))
print(split_outside_quotes(r'"abc"abc', "abc"))
print(split_outside_quotes(r'"abc', "abc"))
```

Output:

```
['"abc"+ h ', ' "abch"']
['']
['"abc"']
['"abc"', '']
['"abc']
```

Note that your expected output of `['"abc"+ h ','"abch"']` doesn't make sense -- there is a space between `abc "abch"'`, so the output should be `['"abc"+ h ', ' "abch"']`. Maybe you want to `strip` the results?

---

This implementation requires quotes to be closed for the text to be considered in quotes:

```py
def split_outside_quotes(string, sep):
    if sep == "":
        raise ValueError("empty separator")
    
    in_quotes_set = set()
    in_quote = False
    for i, char in enumerate(string):
        if char == '"':
            if in_quote:
                in_quotes_set.update(range(prev_quote, i+1))
            else:
                prev_quote = i
            
            in_quote = not in_quote
    
    substrings = []
    split_from = 0
    string_len = len(string)
    sep_len = len(sep)
    i = 0
    while i < string_len:
        if i not in in_quotes_set:
            if string[i:i+sep_len] == sep:
                substrings.append(string[split_from:i])
                i = split_from = i + sep_len
                continue
        
        i += 1
    
    substrings.append(string[split_from:])
    return substrings

print(split_outside_quotes('"abc', "abc"))
print(split_outside_quotes('"abc""abc"abc"abc', "abc"))
```

Output:

```
['"', '']
['"abc""abc"', '"', '']
```

Comment: I'm not too sure what the result for `split_outside_quotes(r'"abc', "abc")` should be, though. Arguably it should return `['"', '']`, but it actually returns `['"abc']`.

Answer (score 1):

I hope the snippet below satisfied your request:
(Assuming you need only to split the first *abc*)

```
string = '"abc"+ h abc "abch"'
def splitit(string, text):
    new = ' '+text+' '
    start = string.index(new) + 1
    #print(start)
    end = start + len(text) + 1
    #print(end)
    print(string[start:end])
    result = []
    result.append(string[:start])
    result.append(string[end:])
    return result

print(splitit(string, 'abc'))
```

result:
`['"abc"+ h ', '"abch"']`

Answer (score -1):

```
Please try this - 


s = '"abc"+ h abc "abch"'
splitted = s.split('abc ')
print(splitted)
```

output - ['"abc"+ h ', '"abch"']